# Teffilas Haderech Jerusalem to Beit Shemesh

Tags: halacha, travel, tefilat-haderech

Is one obligated to say teffilas Haderech when traveling by bus or car from Jerusalem to Beit Shemesh?

Is the distance between them sufficient? Is it one unbroken area of residence?

Travel time without traffic can range from 35-45 minutes

According to Google maps route 1 is the preferred highway to take

In general *when is* one supposed to say tefilas Haderech when traveling in Israel? How much distance must one travel outside of Jerusalem to need to say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ashkenazim say tfilat haderech if traveling one parsa (4 kilometer) along a route empty of habitation. Sefardim say it when traveling 72 minutes.

It looks from knowing the route and [Google Maps](https://www.google.fr/maps/dir/Sho'eva,+Israel/Mesilat+Zion,+Israel/@31.7881598,35.0193165,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x1502d05e3f23477d:0x5c48b82a7b0493c5!2m2!1d35.079003!2d31.799369!1m5!1m1!1s0x1502cf89b8950a03:0x72996deb63625642!2m2!1d35.009463!2d31.801449) that there is indeed a 4-kilometer stretch in an empty zone when leaving Sho'eva before arriving in Mesilat Zion.

For a user-friendly perspetive on the topic see [R Dan Roth at Torah Live](https://torahlive.com/courses/travelling-ultimate-worldview/%20distance). For more traditional sources see [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tefillat_HaDerech) and [halacha.co](http://halacha.co/en/tefilas-haderech/).

As always check with a rav before applying anything you learn on this site.